# Where does the file go after deleting using DEL batch file command in the command prompt?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a simple batch file that runs and deletes itself after running. This app was put on the desktop and will be executed using registry RUNONCE. To self delete it, I'm using this command below.

```
goto 2>nul & del /Q "%APP_PATH%"
```

Unlike this command below, the command above doesn't print any errors in the console.

```
del /Q "%APP_PATH%"
```

The batch file was deleted in the desktop. When we install our internal application (not recovery app), the batch file that was deleted using `DEL` command will be restored to its previous location. I haven't got a chance to check the internal application source code yet. By this level of information, does anyone has an idea of why this weird behavior happens?

Comment: `del` just removes the pointer to the file, marking the occupied sectors as "free" (unlike deleting with explorer, which moves the file to the recycle bin) Chances are, your application doesn't "restore" the file, but writes a new copy.

Comment: @Stephan but where would it get the details to write a new one?

Comment: inside the application.exe or it's installation routine.

Comment: @Stephan This batch file was run through registry RUNONCE does it makes difference?

Comment: The successful deletion depends on a) the exact content of `%APP_PATH%`, b) the setting of the working folder for the task and c) on the permissions for the user the processes is bound to to the according folder. The "recreation" has nothing to do with that (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 1):

The *Windows Command Processor* `cmd.exe` processes a batch file line by line. This means it opens a batch file, reads the next line, parses it, and if there is no more line to read, it closes the batch file. Then it executes the command(s) on the parsed line. See [How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094699/)

The Windows command processor exits the processing of a batch file if there is a serious syntax here. This error condition handling is used here.

Create a batch file with following lines:

```
@echo off
goto
echo Third line!
```

Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/10-ways-to-open-the-command-prompt-in-windows-10/) and run this batch file by typing its full qualified file name, i.e. drive + path + name + extension enclose in double quotes.

There is the following error message output by `cmd.exe` because of batch label is missing on second line.

> No batch label specified to GOTO command.

The third line is not executed anymore by `cmd.exe` because of batch file processing is exited after execution of second command line because of this serious syntax error on which it is unclear for `cmd.exe` where to continue the batch file processing.

Now let us look on the command line:

```
goto 2>nul & del /Q "%APP_PATH%"
```

This is a command line with two commands on one line as described in detail by my answer on [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564).

The first command `goto` with the missing batch label results in exiting the batch file processing. The error message output by `cmd.exe` in this case is redirected with `2>nul` to device **NUL** to suppress it. But the second command `del /Q "%APP_PATH%"` with the already expanded environment variable `%APP_PATH%` is already in the commands queue. For that reason this command is executed next.

Then `cmd.exe` does not even try to open the batch file once more to read the third line as the invalid `goto` command results in exiting batch file processing which in this case does not even exist anymore if `%APP_PATH%` references the name of the batch file.

BTW: `APP_PATH` is a strange because of misleading environment variable name for a **file name** with full path.

Here is an even better example:

Create first a batch file with name `Test1.cmd` with following lines:

```
@echo off
echo %~nx0 is calling Test2.cmd.
call "%~dp0Test2.cmd"
echo %~nx0 is processed further.
```

Create second a batch file with name `Test2.cmd` with following lines:

```
@echo off
set "BatchFile=%~f0"
echo %~nx0 is deleting itself now.
goto 2>nul & del /A /F "%BatchFile%"
```

Then run from within a command prompt window `Test1.cmd`. The output is:

```
Test1.cmd is calling Test2.cmd.
Test2.cmd is deleting itself now.
Test1.cmd is processed further.
```

It can be seen that `Test2.cmd` deleted itself without showing any error message by `cmd.exe` processing `Test2.cmd`. But processing of `Test1.cmd` is continued after `Test2.cmd` deleted itself.

The option `/Q` is not really necessary on deleting a single file and the file definitely exists on running the command. The option `/A` is useful to delete the batch file even if it has the hidden attribute set as otherwise `del` would not delete it. The option `/F` is useful to delete the batch file even if the read-only attribute is set.

Another command method is using as last command line in a batch file which should delete itself the command line:

```
del /A /F "%~f0" & exit
```

But it has a disadvantage as it can be seen on creating a `Test2.cmd` with the lines:

```
@echo off
echo %~nx0 is deleting itself now.
del /A /F "%~f0" & exit
```

Run `Test1.cmd` from within the command prompt window. The batch file `Test2.cmd` deletes itself, but command `exit` results in exiting the `cmd.exe` opened with opening the command prompt window and processing both batch files. For that reason `Test1.cmd` is not further processed and the console window is closed immediately.

Appending the option `/B` after command `exit` would result in not exiting `cmd.exe`, but two error messages would be output by `cmd.exe` because of not finding anymore `Test2.cmd`.

For that reason the usage of `goto 2>nul & del /A /F "%~f0"` is a best practice example for self-deletion of a batch file.

BTW: The order or the two commands matters. The usage of `del /A /F "%~f0" & goto 2>nul` would result in an error message output by `cmd.exe` as in this case it tries to open the already deleted batch file once more.

Comment: I set the variable inside the script `set APP_PATH=%~f0`.